# モバイルでアクセスしたときは、HTML階層構造を変更したい

Tags: html, css

パソコンとモバイルでWebレイアウトを分けたいです。
display:flex;のorderプロパティやメディアクエリを試してみたのですが、どうしてもうまくいきません。
HTML階層構造が異なるからだということに気が付きました。
モバイルでアクセスしたときだけ、HTML階層構造を変更することはできますか？

---

PCからのアクセスを想定。前提となるhtml

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="a">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <p><span></span></p>
  </a>

  <h2><svg></svg><a href=""></a></h2>

  <div>
    <a href=""><button></button></a>
  </div>

  <a href="a"> 
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </a>

  <a href="b"></a>
  <a href="c"></a>
</div>
```

モバイル用アクセスとして変更したいこと。
画像を横に並べたいです。
上の画像を下の画像の所へ移動させ、横に表示させたいです。
2つあるimgタグのリンク先は、同じです。

---

モバイルからのアクセスで表示させたいhtmlを追記しました。

```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <h2><svg></svg><a href=""></a></h2>
    
      <div>
        <a href=""><button></button></a>
      </div>
    
      <a href="a"> 
        <img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </a>
    
      <a href="b"></a>
      <a href="c"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: そもそもモバイルでの仕様通りのHTML組み方がわからないのか？もしくはデバイスごとにHTMLの構造を分ける方法がわからないのか？それとも両方なのか？どれに当たりますか？

Comment: デバイスごとにHTML構造を分ける方法が分かりません。メディアクエリでデバイスごとに「display:none;」指定で切り替えようかと思ったのですが、ブラウザはその部分も読み込むようなので、止めました。

Comment: ではモバイルではどういうHTML構造にしたいのですか？

Comment: モバイルからのアクセスで表示させたいhtmlを、本文へ追記しました

Comment: 動的に書き換えたいなら HTML や CSS だけでなく JavaScript が必要になりそうですし、実際のコンテンツがどんな内容なのか分かりませんが、一般的にモバイル端末の方が表示領域は縦長 (横幅は狭くなる) なので、横に並べられるのは利用者視点であまりうれしくない気もします。

Comment: DOMの構造を動的に変更するのであればjavascriptを駆使する必要があるでしょう。 `display` で丸ごと表示非表示を切り替えれば別に問題なく可能だとは思いますが、この方法がNGな明確な理由があるのでしょうか。（今どきHTMLテキストくらいの転送量は気にする必要もないと思います）どうしてもCSSで実現させたいのであれば、HTMLコードよりデザインカンプを質問本文に記載したほうが皆さんアイディアを出し合ってくれるのではないかと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 画像多用しているサイトでモバイル表示速度を気にしているため、display切り替えはできれば避けたいと考えています。「DOMの構造を動的に変更するのであればjavascriptを駆使する必要がある」ということが分かったので良かったです。最新のCSS・HTML情報を把握できていないため、もしかしたら何か良い方法があるかもしれないと思い質問しました。